# Selenium web driver is throwing an error when trying to click next

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

After running this code, I receive the same error. I thought by changing it from this elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next') to the current code the error would go away but it has persisted.

```
 while True:
        elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="left-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/i')
        if Html_Link == driver.current_url:
            break;
        elm.click()
```

This is the error message I am getting, but I am not sure what exactly I can do to fix it.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <i class="next fa fa-5x fa-arrow-circle-right" ng-click="loadData(1)" role="button" 
tabindex="0" style="color: darkgray;"></i> is not clickable at point (966, 560). Other element would 
receive the click: <div class="hidden-lg footer-links">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Comment: Could you show us the url of your page?

Answer (score 0):

Another element is overlapping the element that you are trying to click on. So the possible solutions

1. Using the javascrip tclick

```
driver.execute_Script("arguments[0].click()",elm)
```

2. find the element which can be clicked without an interception

```
# check if xpath helps in achieving your goal "//div[@class='hidden-lg footer-links']"
```